# My objects are not getting filtered despite setting the get_queryset function in views.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter, django-rest-framework, django-1.11

I want to make an api to get the  detail view of a blog from a list of published blog posts. To solve that, I am using get_queryset() filters to solve this, but it is simply giving back all the list, i.e. no filter worked.

I have used the code as shown below:

models.py

```
class BlogModel (models.Model) :
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    blog = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=254)
```

views.py

```
class BlogRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDeleteAPIView):
    serializer_class=BlogListSerializer
    queryset=BlogModel.objects.all()
    lookup_field='blog_id'

    def get_queryset(self,*args, **kwargs):
        return BlogModel.objects.filter(
            blog__id=self.kwargs['blog_id']
```

serializers.py

```
class BlogListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$',BlogRetrieveView.as_view()),
```

I am getting the following output:

[This shows 1 out of 7 blog post shown in a list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFfDn.png)
Clearly, the filter wasn't applied.

**Edit 1: With the given advices, my code on localhost worked, but the production website is still stuck on a situation mentioned in the problem above. What can be the reason behind it?**

Comment: which url you are trying?

Comment: /api/blog/9

A blog post with id 9 exists. And all the blog posts are being shown, i.e. same as output of /api/blog

Comment: `/api/blog/9/` ... Ends with **`/`** (slash)

Comment: Nope, still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `RetrieveUpdateDeleteAPIView` class, you probably don't want to use `lookup_field='blog_id'` and instead meant to use `lookup_url_kwarg='blog_id'`.  You should also remove your `get_queryset()` method as the view will handle that for you.

When you change this, your view will retrieve the correct value from the URL `r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$'` using the `lookup_url_kwarg` and it will attempt the lookup using the `id` field on the BlogModel.

Also, if your request to `/api/blog/9/` was returning a list then you url configuration must be incorrect because the `RetrieveUpdateDeleteAPIView` class does not return that JSON, it will only return a dictionary-like object of the data from your model.  Is your blog-list url configured as `r'^blog/$'`? (a missing $ at the end may be the cause)

Comment: The knowledge of look_up_kwarg was crucial. Also, as u predicted, the $ in r'^blog/$' was missing. Though the code is working in localhost, its not working in the production website, what can be the reason for this?

Comment: @RJ_SU do you have any more information about the error in production?  Is it the same error?

Comment: I figured it out finally! It all suggested that the server was not restarting with the code changes I made on the git repository. Actually, the restart command I was using was not correct or working properly. The exact command did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete `lookup_field` and `get_queryset()` of BlogRetrieveView and change urls to `url(r'^blog/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',BlogRetrieveView.as_view())`

Comment: The whole method is working in django's latest version. But my website is working on django 1.10 and python 2.7   . It must be having some other ways to do so

Comment: My bad, its django 1.11 itself